# How to click on "Stay on this page" button on confirm Navigation pop-up when i moved one form to other form without save entered value in selenium

Tags: selenium, popup, webdriver

In my application,when i enter some values in available fields and without click on save button if clicked on other available form tab than comes a confirm Navigation pop-up which have buttons "Stay on this page" or "Leave this page".

I have to click on "Stay on this page" button and than click on submit button.
I tried with Alert class `alert.dismiss();` which closed pop-up but i want to click on "stay on this page" button.

Can anyone please help me to do this thing in selenium .

---

When I move from one page to other without clicking on save button i got this confirm Navigation pop-up:

[image]

Comment: add screenshot or html source because it is little bit hard to analyze your scenario.

Comment: Please find below Confirm navigation pop-up.

Comment: @davidrawson ,it's not duplicate i think so. i need solution in selenium webdriver. if you have any solution please provideme .

Comment: Have u tried alert.accept(); method ?

Comment: yes i tried but its not working. by-default focus set on "Leave this page".

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work, First you need to switch on that alert

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

and then change focus to **Stay on this page** tab

```
alert.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.TAB));; //By pressing TAB key in this way
```

and then click the button

```
alert.dismiss();
```

This approach is working at my end